# AttributeError when creating an object with Tuple attribute

Tags: python

I just started working with OOP in Python and I'm asked to create a **class named Square** with a specific **attribute called position, which is of type tuple**. So for each Square object there is a particular method to print it, given the size attribute (prints '#' of size*size) and position attribute **(starts at coordenates (x, y))** but when I have an AttributeError in the **init** method which tells me:

*AttributeError: 'Square' object has no attribute '_Square__position'*

Here's the code:

```
class Square:
''' create Square instance with public attributes
size and position '''
def __init__(self, size=0, position=(0, 0)):
    self.size = size
    self.position = position

''' retrieve size and make it private'''
@property
def size(self):
    return self.__size

''' set private size attribute '''
@size.setter
def size(self, value):
    if type(value) is not int:
        raise TypeError("size must be an integer")
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError("size must be >= 0")
    self.__size = value

''' retrieve position and make it private '''
@property
def position(self):
    return self.__position

''' set private position attribute '''
@position.setter
def position(self, value):
    if value[0] < 0 or value[1] < 0:
        raise TypeError("position must be a tuple of 2 positive integers")
    self.__position[0] = value[0]
    self.__position[1] = value[1]

''' calculates area of square '''
def area(self):
    return self.__size ** 2

''' print a square of # the size of self.__size'''
def my_print(self):
    if self.__size == 0:
        print()
    else:
        for line in range(self.__position[1]):
            print()
        for i in range(self.__size):
            for space in range(self.__position[0]):
                print(" ", end="")
            for j in range(self.__size):
                print('#', end="")
            print()
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please post the entire traceback so we see the flow.

Comment: You have a second problem that is related to the first. Tuples are immutable. Do you want `__position` to be the tuple? If so, you can't do `self.__position[0] = value[0]`. Likely you want to just do `self.__position = value` in the setter. But then why have this be a property at all?

Comment: properties are more expensive than instance variables. They are useful if you want to run extra code when getting or setting (maybe you want validate that position is a tuple before accepting it). Otherwise, you don't need them. "Private" variables can be problematic. By using 2 underscores, the variable name is mangled with the class name. This make inheritance more difficult.

Comment: Name mangling (double underscore prefix) does not make an attribute "private".  There is no way to make an attribute private.  Use a single underscore prefix instead to indicate that the attribute is not public API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__init__()` method should be like this:

```
def __init__(self, size=0, position=(0, 0)):
    self.__size = size    #<-- dunder
    self.__position = position #<-- dunder
```

### Edit

Thanks to @tdelaney who pointed out that `position` is a tuple which doesn't allow **item assignment**. So, your `@position.setter` should be like this:

```
@position.setter
def position(self, value):
    if type(value) != tuple or value[0] < 0 or value[1] < 0:
        raise TypeError("position must be a tuple of 2 positive integers")
    self.__position = value
```

Comment: I can't believe it was just that. Since I made the attribute private with the property setter I thought it could be public in the init function. It worked, thanks!

Comment: @Anwarvic -This likely isn't the answer. You'll see a fail if you try to set position again later - maybe you want to move a square and do `square.position = (3,4)` later. That will fail. Once you fix that, then your original `__init__` will start working again also.

Comment: @tdelaney you're correct... let's fix that for him/her.

Comment: I don't like the solution because you still suggest to use name mangling, for no good reason.

Comment: @wim - I agree that its likely not needed, but I think that its a design decision outside of a strict answer to the question. Answers don't necessarily need to address what isn't asked.